# Перемещение действия из функции в функцию или последовательная остановка функций при выполнении их задачи

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю что-то вроде теста на html и jquery. Есть функция `$(document).ready(function(){})` в которой 4 функции кнопок с вариантами ответов. При нажатии на любую из кнопок, все варианты ответов, как и сам вопрос переписываются на следующие вызванные из трехмерного массива. Также есть счётчик правильных ответов, который делает +1 при нажатии на кнопку с верным ответом. Проблема: понятия не имею как заставить счётчик переходить на другую кнопку чтобы с предыдущей больше +1 не происходило. Я в jquery как и в js в общем нуль, по этому просьба выражаться проще. Либо подскажите как сделать чтоб вторая функция с следующим вопросом и счётчиком выполнялась и не выполнялась первая нет, и т.д. ибо я в последствии еще добавлю. Вот код:

```
var c = 0;
var Asks = [
  ["Вопрос 1", ["Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2", "Кнопка 3", "Кнопка 4"]],
  ["Вопрос 2", ["Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2", "Кнопка 3", "Кнопка 4"]],
  ["Вопрос 3", ["Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2", "Кнопка 3", "Кнопка 4"]]
];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a1").click(function(){
        $("#Counter").html(c += 1);
        $("#Ask").html(Asks[0][0]);
        $("#a1").val(Asks[0][1][0]);
        $("#a2").val(Asks[0][1][1]);
        $("#a3").val(Asks[0][1][2]);
        $("#a4").val(Asks[0][1][3]);
    });
    $("#a2").click(function(){
        $("#Ask").html(Asks[0][0]);
        $("#a1").val(Asks[0][1][0]);
        $("#a2").val(Asks[0][1][1]);
        $("#a3").val(Asks[0][1][2]);
        $("#a4").val(Asks[0][1][3]);
    });
    $("#a3").click(function(){
        $("#Ask").html(Asks[0][0]);
        $("#a1").val(Asks[0][1][0]);
        $("#a2").val(Asks[0][1][1]);
        $("#a3").val(Asks[0][1][2]);
        $("#a4").val(Asks[0][1][3]);
    });
    $("#a4").click(function(){
        $("#Ask").html(Asks[0][0]);
        $("#a1").val(Asks[0][1][0]);
        $("#a2").val(Asks[0][1][1]);
        $("#a3").val(Asks[0][1][2]);
        $("#a4").val(Asks[0][1][3]);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a1").click(function(){
        $("#Ask").html(Asks[1][0]);
        $("#a1").val(Asks[1][1][0]);
        $("#a2").val(Asks[1][1][1]);
        $("#a3").val(Asks[1][1][2]);
        $("#a4").val(Asks[1][1][3]);
    });
    $("#a2").click(function(){
        $("#Counter").html(c += 1);
        $("#Ask").html(Asks[1][0]);
        $("#a1").val(Asks[1][1][0]);
        $("#a2").val(Asks[1][1][1]);
        $("#a3").val(Asks[1][1][2]);
        $("#a4").val(Asks[1][1][3]);
    });
    $("#a3").click(function(){
        $("#Ask").html(Asks[1][0]);
        $("#a1").val(Asks[1][1][0]);
        $("#a2").val(Asks[1][1][1]);
        $("#a3").val(Asks[1][1][2]);
        $("#a4").val(Asks[1][1][3]);
    });
    $("#a4").click(function(){
        $("#Ask").html(Asks[1][0]);
        $("#a1").val(Asks[1][1][0]);
        $("#a2").val(Asks[1][1][1]);
        $("#a3").val(Asks[1][1][2]);
        $("#a4").val(Asks[1][1][3]);
    });
});
```

Comment: "Я в jquery как и в js в общем нуль" - как достали такие признания. Если Вы "нуль", то следует потратить время и силы, чтобы стать не "нуль".

Comment: Если Вы "нуль", то следует потратить время и силы, чтобы стать не "нуль" - как достали такие люди, есть множество обстоятельств по которым человек может просить помощи будучи нулём, а не повышать уровень знаний. Вместо того чтобы просто давать "великолепные" советы в подобном роде, что я и так без вас знаю, лучше бы помогли новичку разобраться

Comment: @Fucus для чего вы используете множественные вызовы `$(document).ready(...)` ?

Comment: @Fucus по этому вопросу существуют разные мнения: кто-то согласен со мной, кто-то - с Вами

Comment: @tilin искал как сделать нормальное подключение кнопок нашёл этот вариант, без множественного вызова функции кнопок не работают (пробовал просто их убрать и ничего)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала Вам в массиве не хватает номеров правильных ответов.

Далее, т.к. число ответов всегда разное, то кнопки логично пересоздавать.

А дальше все просто. При нажатии на кнопку мы проверяем а правильная кнопка нажата? Если да, то увеличиваем счетчик правильных ответов. После этого загружаем новый блок вопросов

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var quest = 0;
  var resp = 0;
  var array = [
    ["Вопрос 1", ["Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2", "Кнопка 3"], 0],
    ["Вопрос 2", ["Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2", "Кнопка 3", "Кнопка 4"], 2],
    ["Вопрос 3", ["Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2"], 1]
  ];

  var fillData = function() {
    var data = $("<div>");
    if (quest >= array.length) {
      data.text('Правильно ответили на ' + resp + ' вопросов');
    } else {
      data.text(array[quest][0]);
      for (var i = 0; i < array[quest][1].length; i++) {
        data = data.add(
        $("<button>")
          .text(array[quest][1][i])
          .data({
            resp: i == array[quest][2]
          })
          .click(function() {
            if ($(this).data('resp'))
              resp++;
            quest++;
            fillData();
          })
          );
      }
    }
    $('#test').empty().append(data);
  };

  fillData();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь не тот массив, вот мой: var Asks = [
["Вопрос 1", ["Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2", "Кнопка 3", "Кнопка 4"]],
["Вопрос 2", ["Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2", "Кнопка 3", "Кнопка 4"]],
["Вопрос 3", ["Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2", "Кнопка 3", "Кнопка 4"]]  
];

Comment: @Fucus А в чем разница? Мой ответ подходит и для этого варианта

Answer (score 0):

```js
let quiz = [
  {
    'question': '2+2?',
    'answers': [ '1', '2', '4', '5' ],
    'rightAnswer': 2
  },
  {
    'question': 'Президент России?',
    'answers': ['Сталин', 'Путин', 'Ленин' ],
    'rightAnswer': 1
  },
  {
    'question': 'Какая степень двойки даст 1024?',
    'answers': ['4', '8', '10' ],
    'rightAnswer': 2
  },
  {
    'question': 'На какой планете ты живешь?',
    'answers': ['Марс', 'Юпитер', 'Сатурн', 'Нибиру', 'Венера', 'Земля' ],
    'rightAnswer': 5
  }
];


let questionBlock = document.querySelector( '#question' ),
    answersBlock = document.querySelector( '#answers' ),
    resultBlock = document.querySelector( '#result' );
    

function setQuestion( { question, answers } ) {
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject) => {
    questionBlock.innerHTML = question;
      
    answers.forEach( ( answer, index ) => {
      let button = document.createElement( 'button' );
          button.innerHTML = answer;
          button.value = index;
          
          button.onclick = ( e ) => {      
            questionBlock.innerHTML = '';
            answersBlock.innerHTML = '';        
            resolve( e.target.value );
          }
      
      answersBlock.appendChild( button );
    } );
  } );
}

async function startQuiz( allQuestions ) {
  let counter = 0;
  
  for( let i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++ ) {
    let currentQuestion = allQuestions[i];
    
    await setQuestion( currentQuestion )
      .then( ( userAnswer ) => {
        if ( userAnswer == currentQuestion.rightAnswer ) {
          counter++;
        }
      } );
  }
  
  return counter;
}

startQuiz( quiz )
  .then( ( result ) => resultBlock.innerHTML = `Количество правильных ответов - ${result}! Мои поздравления!!!` );
```

```html
<div id="quiz">
  <div id="question"></div>
  <div id="answers"></div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В виду уточнения, что число ответов не изменяется, публикую еще один, упрощенный вариант

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var quest = 0;
  var resp = 0;
  var array = [
    ["Вопрос 1", ["Кнопка 1_1", "Кнопка 1_2", "Кнопка 1_3", "Кнопка 1_4"], 1],
    ["Вопрос 2", ["Кнопка 2_1", "Кнопка 2_2", "Кнопка 2_3", "Кнопка 2_4"], 2],
    ["Вопрос 3", ["Кнопка 3_1", "Кнопка 3_2", "Кнопка 3_3", "Кнопка 3_4"], 3],
  ];

  var fillData = function() {
    if (quest >= array.length) {
      alert('Правильно ответили на ' + resp + ' вопросов');
    } else {
      $('#quest').text(array[quest][0]);
      for (var i = 0; i < array[quest][1].length; i++) {
        $("#a" + (i + 1))
          .text(array[quest][1][i])
          .data({
            resp: i == array[quest][2]
          });
      }
    }
  };

  $('#test button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('resp'))
      resp++;
    quest++;
    fillData();
  });
  fillData();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div id="quest"></div>
  <button id="a1"></button>
  <button id="a2"></button>
  <button id="a3"></button>
  <button id="a4"></button>
</div>
```